# I have no style

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

I am tearing my hair out on this one and it seems I am probably not searching the right terms and the google results I get seems to be general layout type of questions.

I have some data that I wish to represent in a web page.  There are some 20~30 fields of different data.  If I were to do it with what I know, I would so something like this(total of 3 columns and 30 rows each field is different data):

```
<table>
<tr><td>Field1:</td><td><input id="dataforField1"></input></td><td>Field2:/td><td><input id="dataforfield2"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field3:</td><td><input id="dataforField3"></input></td><td>Field4:/td><td><input id="dataforfield4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

However I have been reading lately that div is much preferred when presenting non-tabular data.  So I attempted to do this:

```
<div style="float:left;">
<ul>
<li>Field1</li>
<li>Field2</li>
<li>Field3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<ul>
<li><input id="tag1...</li>
<li><input id="tag2...</li>
<li><input id="tag3...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

but my field labels are not lining up with my data input elements.  Field1 seems to match input1 horizontally.  But when I get to field10, it is off by a lot.  I tried it without ul and li and use br after each, but I can't seem to get them to line up.

Question:

1. How do I get them to match if I don't do table?
2. I need clarification on the word "tabular".  If my data were a table, it would only ever going to have 1 row.  When is it okay to use table?
3. What do people use to line things up when they are trying to implement similar things?

Edit:
I want Field1 to line up horizontally with input tag1 and so on.
Edit2:
Added a picture to show how things are not lining up.  it would be the same without li.

Comment: What's wrong with a table...it sounds like this *should* be a table.

Comment: @Paulie_D I will have to disagree. It is really recommended to only use a table when you are actually willing to show a real table with information in it. The old way of presenting forms in tables to achieve alignment is just a no-no these days. Grid systems do it better and they are more responsive.

Comment: To quote the OP *"I have some **data** that I wish to represent in a web page"*....data = tables in my book. Just because the anti-tables groupies are against it doesn't mean you **can't** use a table, especially if it works. Are there other solutions, sure..but sometimes you can go with what just works....if it's a quick effecttive solution I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D Going literally by the words is not what we do as developers. The OP clearly said he wants to display a form. Label, and a text input next to it. Therefore, tables are not the right way to do that. Sure, it works - just like many things do. Is it the proper thing to do? Definite majority says no. Anti-table groupies are not tiny "groupies" anymore. It's the definite majority thesedays. If tables were right, there was no single front-end framework providing complex grid systems.

Comment: Tables were what we had. To this day many forms are written as tables because that's what they are, tables of data to be collected. Grid systems are nice but they aren't always necessary. I didn't say tables were right, I'm just saying they're not wrong either. If it works it's not wrong. Unsemantic or  unpopular doesn't make it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally suggest adopting a grid system for this purpose. There are many great ones. My favorite one for web development is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)'s grid. Bootstrap as a framework is amazing as well.

I will also add a quote of my comment regarding this:

> ... It is really recommended to only use a table when you are actually
>   willing to show a real table with information in it. The old way of
>   presenting forms in tables to achieve alignment is just a no-no these
>   days. Grid systems do it better and they are more responsive.

However.

The disalignment was caused by loss of relativity between the text (labels) and the input fields. As the list goes longer, the proportions are losing. This is because the height of the text is not the same as the height of the input field.

CSS:

```
li {
    height: 40px;
}
```

This makes sure all `<li>` elements will have the same height. Of course it's recommended to apply the style to a class and not directly to an element, but this is just for the sake of the solution.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/arielweinberger/pen/jqveoX

I haven't managed to re-produce what you said you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick answer, those inputs are meant to be input tabs.  Fields are supposed to be labels for those inputs.

Comment: @user691856 Edited my answer with an updated codepen. Can you also upload your code to codepen/jsfiddle? I am not sure if I understand the issue.

Comment: @user691856 Now I got you! Check the CodePen now. Adding height to the `<li>` elements make sure they never lose relativity.

Answer (score 0):

For labels and inputs you should use, you guessed it: `label`s and `input`s. Put each pair under the same parent, make them `inline-blocks` with a fixed width and you're good to go. No need for external tools, this is as basic as it gets.

```css
label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;">
<ul>
  <li><label>Field1</label><input/></li>
  <li><label>Field2</label><input/></li>
  <li><label>Field3</label><input/></li>
  <li><label>Field4</label><input/></li>
  <li><label>Field5</label><input/></li>
  <li><label>Long Field Name</label><input/></li>
  <li><label>Field6</label><input/></li>
  <li><label>Field7</label><input/></li>
</ul>
</div>
```